# Change system registry values on vb.net

Tags: vb.net, registry

I want to change my computer's system registry value via vb.net

```vb
 Dim regKey As RegistryKey

    regKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Ole", True)
    regKey.SetValue("EnableDCOM", "Y")
    regKey.Close()
```

I've tried the above, however it gives no error but it simply doesn't change the value...

Comment: Are you running as admin?

Answer (score 1):

I hardly use VB, but I believe the below is the correct approach.

```
 Dim autoshell = My.Computer.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon", True)
    '' Set the value to 0
    autoshell.SetValue("autorestartshell", 0)
    autoshell.Close()
```

If you experience errors, you need to check that:

- You have permissions to read/write to the registry.
- The subkey you are trying to change actually exists.

You should also consult the  MSDN [VB Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy6azwf7.aspx).